# Assigning SELECT COUNT(*) Query Result to a Java Variable

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc, resultset

I have been having problems assigning the result of a `SELECT COUNT(*)` query to a Java variable. I am assigning the result of the query to a ResultSet.  Then, I am trying to retrieve the value of the count and assigning it to a variable.  I am getting an error when trying to do this.

Here is my code:

```
ResultSet rc1 = null;
int rowCount1;
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

rc1 = stat.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS rowcount1 
   FROM Signal WHERE SignalId = 1;");

if (rc1.next())
        rowCount1 = rc1.getInt("rowcount1");
```

Then I get the following error:

> java.sql.SQLException: no such column: 'rowcount1'
>   at org.sqlite.RS.findColumn(RS.java:116)
>   at org.sqlite.RS.getInt(RS.java:219)

Apparently, the problem is when trying to assign what goes after AS to a variable.  I can't find a lot of information on queries containing AS.  I get the same error with queries where I am not counting.  For example if I have the following code:

```
ResultSet rp1 = null;
int rowCount1 = 0;
Statement stat = conn.createStatement();

rp1 = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Signal AS Sig1 
  FROM Observations WHERE SignalId = 1;");

if (rp1.next())
       rowCount1 = rp1.getInt("rowcount1");
```

I get the same error with the previous code (no such column: rowCount1). What I am doing wrong?  I am making sure the table I am reading contains the correct values so the query has to be true.

Comment: Are you sure you get the correct result from a query such as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Signal WHERE SignalID = '12345'`, when you pull the `COUNT(*)` value itself?

Comment: @kunal, thanks for editing, but next time please take the time to clean up the code as well so it does not run off the screen.......

Comment: your question is tagged `mysql` but driver looks like sqlite  `org.sqlite.RS.findColumn`. can you check your driver once.

Comment: Don't include a trailing `;` in your queries when you query through JDBC

Comment: Yes, I am getting the correct result but for some reason it can not assign it to a variable.

Comment: getInt(0) won't work @Srinivas -- the column numbering starts at 1.

Answer (score 8):

Simply use `rp1.getInt(1)` -- this returns the first column from the resultset as an int -- which is what you want.

If you have more values use `rp1.getInt(2)` to get the second value etc...

Comment: Ok, what about the second example I am providing.  Let's say the query is returning multiple values not just one.  How do I assign those values to a variable?

Comment: Sorry, I found out that I entered something wrong in the second example.

Comment: you can still use column indexing rather that column names, regardless of how many columns your query returns, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Ok, let me try some of this suggestions.  Thanks

Comment: The error went away.  Seem like it is better to stick to the column indeces.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: using column indeces helps with the speed a bit as well as the driver doesn't have to look in the dictionary to identify the column.

Comment: @Liv, the speed advantage will be negligible, unless you're running your select query in a tight loop, and then the `select count(*)` will take up 99%+ of the time.

Comment: you're right -- I'm not aware of the context these queries are running in and as such it could be indeed a minor optimization. Speaking of optimizations though, I would suggest using `select count(1)` rather than `select count(*)` - another minor one :)

Answer (score 0):

The second example has an error:

```
rp1 = stat.executeQuery("SELECT Signal AS Sig1 
  FROM Observations WHERE SignalId = 1;");
...
   rowCount1 = rp1.getInt("rowcount1")
```

will always fail because you have no `rowcount1` column in your query.

Comment: -1 `select count(*) as rowcount1` creates a column called 'rowcount1' in the query. Java doesn't seem to allow getting named columns from a query, but that's another matter.

Comment: I know.. I was referring to the second example.
Query: `SELECT Signal AS Sig1 FROM Observations WHERE SignalId = 1;`

And then he does a: `rp1.getInt("rowcount1");` but there was no rowcount1 in the original query.

Comment: I see, edited your answer to unlock the vote and fixed the vote.